# Legendre's symbol conditions on prime p

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The question: What are the necessary and sufficient conditions on $p$ for which the legendre symbol $$\left(\frac 5p\right)= 1 ?$$ PS: $p$ is an odd prime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By [quadratic reciprocity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity#Legendre.27s_version_of_quadratic_reciprocity), we find  $$\left(\frac{5}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{p}{5}\right),$$

thus the conition is $p\equiv \pm1\pmod5.$ (There are only $5$ residues with reference to $5.$)
Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry I still don't get it

Comment: Would you like to explain where you are stuck?

Comment: You've flipped the legendre symbol using quadratic reciprocity, but how did you arrive at the condition $p\equiv \pm1\pmod5?$

Comment: $p$ must be congruent modulu $5$ to one of $0, 1, 2, 3 ,4,$ and which ones satisfy the condition?

Comment: it will be congruent to 1 mod 5, but why will it be congruent to -1? If it's congruent to -1 then the answer for the above question can't be 1.

Comment: @Paradox101 I mean: there are five possibilities $p\equiv k\pmod5, k\in\{0,1,2,3,4\}.$ And you can examine each case and find that only the two cases $k=1, 4$ are possible when $\left(\frac{p}{5}\right)=1.$ Also, I responded with some delay because I was trying to prove the reciprocity in an elementary way, e.g. by means of linear algebra, but later you showed that the reciprocity was at your disposal, so... in any case, do you understand the argument now?

Comment: Oh ok. I think I get it now. So basically we've used quadratic reciprocity to flip the symbol and then using hit and trial we determine when the symbol will be equal to one. $p\equiv 4\pmod5$ and $p\equiv -1\pmod5$ is essentially the same thing right?

Comment: Right, you got it.